# Initialization of Class fields

Tags: java

```
public class InitializationTest {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int sumOFXandY = x + y;

    public InitializationTest(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getSumOFXandY() {
        return sumOFXandY;
    }
}

class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InitializationTest initializationTest = new InitializationTest(5, 6);
        System.out.println(initializationTest.getX());
        System.out.println(initializationTest.getY());
        System.out.println(initializationTest.getSumOFXandY());
        System.out.println(initializationTest.getX() + initializationTest.getY());
    }
}

 Output:
 5
 6
 0 //Why not 11?
 11
```

In the example above my brain cannot understand such simple thing - a revelation.

When the class is created, its fields are initialized with default values. In this case those are **0**.

Upon calling the constructor **x** is initialized with **5** and **y** is initialized with **6**. Why then **sumOFXandY** is somewhere aside and still is initialized with **0** even after calling the constructor. Why is not it initialized with **5 + 6 = 11** ?

Comment: what does "even after calling the constructor" means? `sumOFXandY` is initialized after x and y, before the constructor is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it(`sumOFXandY`) cannot be *re-initialized* after the constructor gets executed. When you create an object, it initializes the instance variables that are initialized inline (here it is `sumOFXandY` = `x` + `y`). Then the constructor block gets executed.

To solve this, move `sumOFXandY = x + y` inside the constructor.